# "Continuellement" contre "continûment"

Tags: usage, synonymes

> Pendant les évolutions rapides, à chaque trajet la pression
>   finale est plus grande que ce qu’elle aurait été pendant un trajet lent. Ainsi, la pression s’élève progressivement sur le diagramme pression-volume
>   : l’excédent de travail investi pendant les compressions, et le défaut
>   de travail récupéré pendant la détente, se traduisent par une augmentation
>   de l’énergie interne du gaz, dont la température augmente *continuellement*.

Après la lecture de l'article ici :

http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/continu-continuel-a127005584

je me demande pourquoi l'auteur emploie continuellement et non continûment.

Comment: Si 'à chaque trajet' signifie qu'on parle de cycles, alors 'continuellement' (et 'progressivement') doivent sans doute être entendus d'un cycle au suivant. Et on peut difficilement utiliser 'continûment' pour un phénomène discret. Mon problème demeure de comprendre le sens de la phrase, avant de pouvoir choisir le mot adapté.

Comment: @MathieuBouville Vous avez raison. Je comprends bien. Continuellement c'est le mot approprié ici, puisque la température ne s'augmente pas continûment (mathématiquement parlant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Continu*** et ***Continûment*** diffèrent de *Continuel* et *Continuellement*, en ce que *Continu* et *Continûment* se disent des choses qui ne sont pas divisées ni interrompues, depuis leur commencement jusqu'à leur fin;

et que ***Continuel*** et ***Continuellement*** se disent aussi de celles qui sont interrompues, mais qui recommencent souvent et à de courts intervalles.

[Source](http://www.dicoperso.com/term/adb1aea4acaca65f5ab0,,xhtml)